# How do I use the GNU linker instead of the Darwin Linker?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, operating-system, ld

I'm running OS X 10.12 and I'm developing a basic text-based operating system. I have developed a boot loader and that seems to be running fine. My only problem is that when I attempt to compile my kernel into pure binary, the linker won't work. I have done some research and I think that this is because of the fact OS X runs the Darwin linker and not the GNU linker. Because of this, I have downloaded and installed the GNU binutils. However, it still won't work...

Here is my kernel:

```
void main() {
    // Create pointer to a character and point it to the first cell of video
    // memory (i.e. the top-left)
    char* video_memory = (char*) 0xb8000;

    // At that address, put an x
    *video_memory = 'x';
}
```

And this is when I attempt to compile it:

```
Hazims-MacBook-Pro:32 bit root# gcc -ffreestanding -c kernel.c -o kernel.o
Hazims-MacBook-Pro:32 bit root# ld -o kernel.bin -T text 0x1000 kernel.o --oformat binary
ld: unknown option: -T
Hazims-MacBook-Pro:32 bit root#
```

I would love to know how to solve this issue. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You have an extra space and you miss a `=` sign in `-T text 0x1000` which should be `-Ttext=0x1000`. See the manual. If it still doesn't work, try `--section-start=.text=0x1000` as per the manual again.

Comment: @Jester It gives me this error when attempting what you said: 'ld: unknown option: --section-start=.text=0x1000'

Comment: What does `ld --version` say?

Comment: ld --version didn't work so i tried ld -v and it came up with this: '@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-274.1
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em (tvOS)
LTO support using: LLVM version 8.0.0, (clang-800.0.42.1)
TAPI support using: Apple TAPI version 1.30'

Comment: That is not the GNU linker as you claimed. Either you didn't install it properly or you are not invoking the correct binary.

Comment: @Jester I would like to know how to invoke the GNU linker as I can only know how to invoke the Darwin Linker

Comment: Figure out where you installed it and invoke it with full path.

Answer (score 1):

`-T` is a gcc compiler flag, not a linker flag.  Have a look at this:

> With these components you can now actually build the final kernel. We use the compiler as the linker as it allows it greater control over the link process. Note that if your kernel is written in C++, you should use the C++ compiler instead.
>
> You can then link your kernel using:

`i686-elf-gcc -T linker.ld -o myos.bin -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib boot.o kernel.o -lgcc`

> Note: Some tutorials suggest linking with i686-elf-ld rather than the compiler, however this prevents the compiler from performing various tasks during linking.
>
> The file myos.bin is now your kernel (all other files are no longer needed). Note that we are linking against libgcc, which implements various runtime routines that your cross-compiler depends on. Leaving it out will give you problems in the future. If you did not build and install libgcc as part of your cross-compiler, you should go back now and build a cross-compiler with libgcc. The compiler depends on this library and will use it regardless of whether you provide it or not.

This is all taken directly from [OSDev](http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones#Writing_a_kernel_in_C), which documents the entire process, including a bare-bones kernel, very clearly.

Comment: While that is true, I think OP is trying to set the section start for which ld does have a `-Ttext` option.

Comment: Must be my linker, then.  No `-T` option here. :)

Comment: @DavidHoelzer That gives me this error  'Hazims-MacBook-Pro:32 bit root# gcc -T 0x1000 -o myos.bin -ffreestanding kernel.c ////
ld: unknown option: -T /////
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)'

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in that you probably want binutils for this especially if you're coding baremetal; while clang as is purports to be a cross compiler it's far from optimal or usable here, for various reasons. noticing you're developing on ARM I infer; you want this.

## https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm

Aside from the fact that gcc does this thing better than clang markedly, there's also the issue that ld does not build on OS X from the binutils package; it in some configurations silently fails so you may in fact never have actually installed it despite watching libiberty etc build, it will even go through the motions of compiling the source of that target sometimes and just refuse to link it... to the fellow with the lousy tone blaming OP, if you had relevant experience ie ever had built this under this condition you would know that is patently obnoxious. it'd be nice if you'd refrain from discouraging people from asking legitimate questions.

In the CXXfilt package they mumble about apple-darwin not being a target; try changing FAKE_TARGET to instead of mn10003000-whatever or whatever they used, to apple-rhapsody some time.

You're still in way better shape just building them from current if you say need to strip relocations from something or want to work on restoring static linkage to the system. which is missing by default from that clang installation as well...anyhow it's not really that ld couldn't work with macho, it's all there, codewise in fact...that i am sure of

Regarding locating things in memory, you may want to refer to a linker script

## http://svn.screwjackllc.com/?p=noid.git;a=blob_plain;f=new_mbed_bs.link_script.ld

As i have some code in there that will directly place things in memory, rather than doing it on command line it is more reproducible to go with the linker script. it's a little complex but what it is doing is setting up a couple of regions of memory to be used with my memory allocators, you can use malloc, but you should prefer not to use actual malloc; dynamic memory is fine when it isn't dynamic...heh...

The script also sets flags for the stack and heap locations, although they are just markers, not loaded til go time, they actually get placed, stack and heap, by the startup code, which is in assembly and rather readable and well commented (hard to believe, i know)... neat trick, you have some persistence to volatile memory, so i set aside a very tiny bit to flip and you can do things like have it control what bootloader to run on the next power cycle. again you are 100% correct regarding the linker; seems to be you are headed the right direction. incidentally another way you can modify objects prior to loading them , and preload things in memory, similar to this method, well there are a ton of ways, but, check out objcopy and objdump...you can use gdb to dump srecs of structures in memory, note the address, and then before linking but after assembly use dd  to insert the records you extracted with gdb back in to extracted sections..is one of my favorite ways just because is smartass route :D also, if you are tight on memory ever and need to precalculate constants it's one way to optimize things...that way is actually closer to what ld is doing, just doing it by hand... probably path of least resistance on this now though is linker script.